# What is the best method for loading in dependencies & instantiating object only once in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, promise, singleton

I'd like to explore battle-tested, proven design patterns in Javascript that ensure loading in dependencies only once (if they were already loaded in) & instantiates an object only once as well in the DOM.

Specifically, i have following:

```
// Block A in the DOM
<script>
//instantiate my golden object as follows
var some_unique_options = {
   "option1": "some-val",
   "option2": "some-val"
     }
   $.ajaxSetup({cache:true});
   $.getScript('my_golden_script.js', function(){
        golden_object.init(some_unique_options);
    });
</script>

// Block B in the DOM
<script>
//instantiate my golden object as follows
var another_unique_options ={
    "option1": "some-val",
    "option2": "some-val"
   }
   $.ajaxSetup({cache:true});
   $.getScript('my_golden_script.js', function(){
        golden_object.init(another_unique_options);
   });
</script>
```

Currently, my `golden_object` implements a singleton as per: http://robdodson.me/javascript-design-patterns-singleton/

Intended behavior here is that, when the above Bock A & B execute top to bottom in the DOM, `golden_object.init` in Block B would leverage resources defined during the operation of Block A. Business requirement is as such that Block A & B would be identical, and there could be more in the DOM. After several days of researching, I'm still unable to come up with a solid structure. My singleton keeps re-creating itself as new, and only if i call `golden_object.init();` in the devtools console, it would use the existing object in the DOM. How can i get this to work the way it's supposed to? what/where am i making a mistake here?

FYI, `golden_object.js` does carry `$.fn.someOtherObj` & couple of dependencies via `$.getScript()` as well as the definition of the singleton (i wanted Singleton obj to be user interface)

Million thanks to your insights & suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a wrapper around `jQuery.getScript` that ensures the script is loaded only once, and, in the case of the second and further instances, calls the `callback` once the first script has loaded

```
jQuery.getScriptOnce = (function($) {
    var urls = {};
    return function(url, callback) {
        var obj = urls[url];
        if (!obj) {
            urls[url] = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                $.getScript(url, function(script, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    resolve({script: script, textStatus: textStatus, jqXHR: jqXHR});
                    callback(script, textStatus, jqXHR);
                });
            });
        } else {
            obj.then(function(val) {
                callback(val.script, val.textStatus, val.jqXHR);
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

this has the benefit of only needing to change all occurrences of `$.getScript` to `$.getScriptOnce`

Note: I haven't checked to see if `jQuery.getScript` returns a jQuery promise, if it does, then the code can be a lot simpler

> Just tested and it seems getScript DOES return a jquery promise - so you can simply do

```
jQuery.getScriptOnce = (function($) {
    var urls = {};
    return function(url) {
        return urls[url] = urls[url] || $.getScript(url);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

but you'll change

```
$.getScript('my_golden_script.js', function(){
    golden_object.init(some_unique_options);
});
```

to

```
$.getScriptOnce('my_golden_script.js').then(function(){
    golden_object.init(some_unique_options);
});
```